# Georeferencing a geological map of the Yozgat-134 quadrangle

Tags: georeferencing, utm, geology

I need to georeference a Turkish geological map that has no apparent reference points. The description says it has a UTM projection, but no further specifications are provided. How can I figure out what the reference points at the corners of this geological map are (in any)?
[image]

Comment: You should try to obtain the reference grid featured at the base of the map.

Comment: Is there a higher resolution image available online? Can georeference that quickly.

Comment: Sorry @Mapperz, the high-resolution map is copyrighted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten minutes with the georeferencer finding place-names that are on your image gives me this:

[image]

The red dots are the reference points. You click on the point in the image and then locate them on the main QGIS canvas, in this case using an OSM background layer.

Its not perfect (partly because it took ten minutes) as can be seen by slight misalignment of image with OSM b/g in some areas:

[image]

but this could be errors in my point references, or new roads being built off of old ones, or warping of the map when scanned etc.

Noticing the little diagram of the division of Turkiye into these map squares at the bottom..

[image]

...I can see my digitised corners are at:

```
39.999450,34.999446
39.50078,35.49901
```

which makes me think the grid is half-degrees. The actual grid coordinates for this would then be (40, 35) top left and (39.5, 35.5) bottom right. If you crop the image precisely to the map then you can  write a simple "world file" with the coordinate info to register it.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you do not need to use the corners for georeferencing. Any locations on your map that are identifiable in some base data will do.  [See here for QGIS help with georeferencing](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/map_georeferencing.html).

Your map has cities and roads so if you were to add something like Open Street Maps to QGIS you would have the reference points you need to do the georeferencing. Any intersection of roads would be perfect for use as reference points since they are easy to see on your map and your base data. Make sure you spread your points out across your map.

Of course, your georeferencing would only be as good as the accuracy of the OSM data (plus the errors from georeferencing process).